# Code Is Saying "Attempt to compare number <= Instance"

Tags: lua, roblox

It says

> Players.ninjafox56.PlayerGui.Shop.ShopGui.LightSide.ChooseSideL:5: attempt to compare number <= Instance

```
Rank = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Rank
Power = game.Players.LocalPlayer.leaderstats.Power

if Power >= 10000 then
    Rank.Value = 'Light'
else
    script.Parent.Text = 'Not Enough Power'
    wait(3)
    script.Parent.Text = 'Light Side'
  end
end)
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit, what you try to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `Power` is an object inside `leaderstats`, I'm going to assume it's a [NumberValue](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/NumberValue).

When you say

```
if Power >= 10000 then
```

You are comparing the NumberValue [Instance](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/Instance) against the number. You are not comparing the number stored inside `Power` to the number, that's where your error is coming from. To fix this, use the [NumberValue's Value](https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/property/NumberValue/Value) in the comparison:

```
if Power.Value >= 10000 then
```

Comment: Ohhhhhh… that makes soo much more sense thanks :D